# Http contents are not loading in Https page

Tags: http, ssl, https, webresource.axd, scriptresource.axd

We recently implemented SSL to some of the web pages and after that loading functionality stopped working. While going through browser console I am getting the following error:

[blocked] The page at 'https://example.org' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://example.org/ScriptResource.axd': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

Please help me on this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What browser do you use? You should only get a small icon in the address bar, that this happened...

Comment: In google chrome it is not at all loading ajax Panel and in IE11 asking for permission to load insecure content if I click yes then it will work in IE 11. In Mozilla it is working fine.

Comment: Hmm, there is nothing you can do. Get rid of all `http`, since it is not increasing credibility for the user, if *any* message pops up.